# Centos - yum update throws postfix error by dependencies

Tags: mysql, centos, digital-ocean

I have a fresh centos 7 installation at azure.com and I decided to install a web server, but I'm new with Centos so I decided to follow the Digital Ocean guide [How to install MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7).

The problem is that when I use `yum update` it throws this error:

```
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64 (@base)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@updates)
           libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-
       community)Not found
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-
community)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64 (@base)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@updates)
           libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-
community)
           Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What do I have to do to restore the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the package is Obsoleted.

Search for the mysql and install from the found results.

do

`yum search mysql`

and select the version from the list.

Comment: twhot aother error...

Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: etc........

Comment: you might want to purge mysql and try to reinstall.

Comment: Package(s) mysql-community-server.x86_64 available, but not installed.


i think maybe its when i've follow that guide i add a new rpm file or somethign like that and made a bug.

Comment: yep just do yum install mysql-community-server.x86_64

Comment: sony nothing changed... same issue... its there a way to reverse that step? (following the guide of digital ocean)